# how can so called "unallocated" IP adresses appear in web logs?

Tags: networking, ipv6

My server is currently experiencing some web app attack to which miscellaneous IPv6 addresses are participating.

Several of these addresses are said belonging to so called *unallocated networks*

None of these addresses are currently being report on the major lists of dirty IPs

As an example of these : 2002:d15a:e1c3::d15a:e1c3
The remarks section of the whois notes : *This object is here for Database consistency.*

How can this be possible ? Is it worth blacklisting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7526) 6to4 address, as is any address beginning with `2002:`.

6to4 is an IPv6 transition technology that creates an IPv6 tunnel. In its public anycast form, the 6to4 IPv6 address has a 1:1 correspondence with the endpoint's IPv4 address. In this case, the 6to4 address [2002:d15a:e1c3::d15a:e1c3](https://ip.addr.space/2002:d15a:e1c3::d15a:e1c3) corresponds to [209.90.225.195](https://ip.addr.space/209.90.225.195).

That machine didn't use native IPv6 connectivity, but instead used a 6to4 tunnel through a public 6to4 anycast relay, possibly to attempt to obscure its origin. It could possibly also be misconfiguration; some operating systems (such as Windows) enable public 6to4 by default.

Comment: That does make sense. Among other IPv4 addresses involved in the attack, several belong to the WOW network. Thanks Michael for that piece of valuable information.

Comment: I can't wait for the public 6to4 relays to finally shut down. In the meantime, web sites can generally get away with blocking `2002::/16` as actual web browsers will retry on IPv4 (due to Happy Eyeballs).

Comment: The RFC that you link explicitly says that 2002::/16 is **not** deprecated. Only 192.88.99.1 is deprecated. And you cannot tell from the log if the client actually used a public 6to4 relay. It's likely that the client used a public 6to4 relay, but there are other ways the packets could have been delivered from the client to the server.

Comment: @kasperd The prefix itself is not deprecated, just the service that uses it. As a practical matter this makes no difference in this situation. As the RFC also mentions, private 6to4 is called 6rd and uses ISP-owned prefixes rather than 2002::/16. I suppose it's possible someone put up a public 6to4 anycast relay on some address other than 192.88.99.1, but I've never heard of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Maybe you've never heard of it, but that is actually how 6to4 was defined when the RFC was first published. Though at the time the addresses were more likely unicast than anycast. And there was even a site with [a list](https://web.archive.org/web/20010604065249/http://www.kfu.com:80/~nsayer/6to4/) of relays to choose from. The use of the 192.88.99.1 anycast address was a later addition, and it's only that later addition to 6to4 which has been deprecated.

Comment: @kasperd Yeah, I missed that. I only started using IPv6 in 2006, so I did miss a bunch of the very early stuff if it didn't make it into an RFC (and maybe some stuff that did).